# Why are some upvotes missing?

Tags: support, reputation, up-votes

I answered some questions and i can see that others have up voted my answer but I don't see any points added to my reputation and the total reputation points are the same!

I took a picture of it. Do you know what is happening? :D[image]

Comment: Had you possibly already reached the limit of 200/day (not including acceptances)? I see you've passed that by now.

Comment: Yeah, i've reached 215. Is that the limit for a day?

Comment: The limit from upvotes is 200 a day. Reputation from accepted answers, accepting an answer on your own question and receiving a bounty are immune to this reputation cap.

Comment: [You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day from any combination of the activities below. Only bounty awards and accepted answers are not subject to the daily reputation limit](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: Thanks @Mari-LouA

Comment: Reaching the daily reputation cap also earns you [mortarboard badge](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/badges/25/mortarboard?userid=33118).